# Does an All-in-One printer need to be connected to a PC to photocopy?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

I need to buy an All-in-One Printer just for photo-copying some documents.

Since my dad gonna use it and he doesn't know much about computers, all I want to know is if the printer needs to be connected to a PC just for photocopy?

The models I am looking to buy is either of these two:

- HP Deskjet 2050 All-in-One - J510a Printer
- HP Deskjet 1050 All-in-One - J410a Printer.

The problem is, I need to buy them online to save some time, and I am not very fond of online shopping. So, if you can just tell me if those models needs PC connection while copying or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have owned several HP "all-in-one" devices. None of them needed a PC connected in order to make a photocopy.

Just make it clear to the vendor that standalone copying is the purpose for which you are purchasing the device. Where I live, we have legal rights to return goods which are unfit for purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It does not; photocopying is independent of printing.

Answer (score 0):

No all in one don't need a PC to get a photo copy from it. You only need a PC to print and scan purpose only. Even for fax you don't need PC.

Comment: Some models can even print pictures from thumb drives or flash cards without involving a PC.

Comment: And some “multi-function devices” can scan with output to a USB drive, without using a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Brother all-in-one, I've made a copy with the PC not powered up.  It's only ethernet connected anyway.

However, your mention of HP worries me.  Some years ago I ran into a HP printer that did some of it's work on the PC's processor.  If anything went wrong (an incomplete print job was always an example of something wrong) you had to reboot the **PC** to clear the error, power cycling the printer did nothing.  I do not know if they still do such an abomination but it's certainly something I would worry about.

Have you tried asking HP?